# ubuntu 12.04 - keep getting "Server not found" for some websites 

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, browser, website

ever since last week , i've noticed that many websites cannot be accessed , and it doesn't matter if i use firefox or chromium as a web browser .

as an example of such a website is:

http://tutorials-android.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/layout-animation-in-android.html

all i get is a "Server not found" error page . sometimes after a few refreshes it works just fine .

i've checked it on a windows OS machine that is connected to the exact same LAN network , and the website is shown just fine .

i've also checked the /etc/hosts file and it doesn't contain anything suspicious .

what is going on? how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you configured your machine to know where to find a DNS server?

Comment: i haven't done any tweaking of this kind.